# ValidateRequest="False" inside a master page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

My application uses a single aspx page, and dynamically loads in master pages based on the url.

I have a few secured master pages that have forms that need to post html, so I have to set ValidateRequest="false". This of course isn't available in the @Master directive, only the @Page directive. I don't want to disable this security setting site-wide, so is there an alternate way of accomplishing this at the master page level?

I'm referring to the "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client" error message you get when posting a page with html markup.

I don't think I can use web.config either as it's the same physical url that's serving up the entire site.

My only thought is to use javascript to encode the input.

Thanks.

Comment: So you have one content page that loads multiple master pages?

Comment: @CheckRaise - yes - one index.aspx page. App uses a combination of url rewriting and dynamic master pages.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Confused Request validation with Event Validation.
*Why not set Page's ValidateRequest also, based on URL.*
But just out of curiosity, why did you choose that approach? to have one content page and vary the master? Are you applying theming based on the URL?

As it seems you cannot set ValidateRequest property dynamically. It has to be set either in the page directive, or Web.config.

Try using Page.EnableEventValidation = true, if that gives the needed result.

Comment: how do you set ValidateRequest in codebehind? I'm only aware of the page directive or web.config. I suppose that's my question.

Comment: And to answer your question - it's a content management system that allows the user to choose a template (master page) for the content that they're authoring. It uses friendly urls that are mapped to a common aspx page in the root of the site.

Comment: Page.EnableEventValidation = true/false;
P.S. Make sure to set it on Page_Init event, or Page_PreRender

Comment: Also you could have stayed within One Mater One content architecture and change layouts based on Themes...